# Таймер на пайтон

Tags: python

Пытаюсь создать просто таймер, который работает как обычный, то-есть отсчитывать время от полуночи, до полуночи, но плохо выходит. Подскажите, что не так?

```
import time

seconds = 57
minutes = 0
hours = 0

while seconds < 60:
    print(seconds,':',minutes,':',hours)
    seconds += 1
    minutes += 1
    hours += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes += 1
    elif minutes == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes = 0
        hours += 1
```

Comment: Гораздо проще иметь 1 счетчик - секунд. Увеличивать его на +1, в полночь обнулять, При выводе - переводить секунды в минуты и часы.

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` не знаю как в Питоне, но в других языках, sleep гарантирует что задержка будет не менее указанной, но не гарантирует, что она будет не более. То есть ваши часы будут отставать, так как по факту задержка будет 1,00***+ секунд.

Comment: @Kromster, (к первому комментарию) этот вариант есть в моем ответе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

вы каждую секунду прибавляете и по секунде и по минуте и по часу:

```
seconds += 1
minutes += 1
hours += 1
```

а затем, если секунд 60 то еще раз прибавляете по минуте :)

вторая ваша ошибка

```
if seconds == 60:
    ...
elif minutes == 60:
```

вы этим `elif` говорите, что у вас не возможна ситуация когда и секунд 60 и минут 60 - но в жизни это не так

третья ваша ошибка - в бесконечном цикле

с одной стороны у вас цикл пока не будет 60 секунд;

```
while seconds < 60:
```

но с другой стороны вы внутри цикла обрабатываете ситуацию когда секунд 60 и сбрасываете счётчик секунд в 0, таким образом когда доходит до проверки условия в цикле - секунд никогда не бывает 60

вам достаточно такого кода:

```
seconds = 57
minutes = 0
hours = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(1)

    print(seconds,':',minutes,':',hours)
    seconds += 1

    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes += 1

    if minutes == 60:
        minutes = 0
        hours += 1
```

если делать по красоте - я бы делал так:

```
seconds, minutes, hours = (57, 0, 0)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)

    print(f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}")
    seconds += 1

    seconds, minutes, hours = (0, minutes + 1, hours) if seconds == 60 else (seconds, minutes, hours)
    seconds, minutes, hours = (seconds, 0, hours + 1) if minutes == 60 else (seconds, minutes, hours)
```

Comment: @Satseki, я вам так второй вариант кода кинул - просто для любопытства как можно код сделать покомпактнее и покрасивее

Comment: `f""` - это f-строки, в них через `{}` можно указывать переменные, `:02d` говорит о том, что числа выводить надо в виде 2 цифр, если цифр меньше - ставить недостающие 0, значение нескольким переменным удобно задавать через кортежи - `x, y = (1, 5)` (например) ну и условие зачастую удобно писать в 1 строчку - тернарным оператором `результат = значание1 условие else значение 2`, например если условие без `else` то можно записать `a = b if c else a` - если условие выполнится, то запишется `b` иначе `a` - т.е. технически ничего не запишется

Answer (score 4):

Возможно будет полезно, решение с помощью модуля [`datetime`](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-datetime.html) из стандартной библиотеки Python:

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

current_time = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, 0, 57))

while True:
    print(current_time.time().isoformat())
    sleep(1.0)
    current_time += timedelta(seconds=1)
```

---

Еще вариант, можно хранить время в секундах, а выделять отдельно часы/минуты/секунды уже при выводе, это намного упрощает логику программы:

```
import time

seconds = 57

while True:
    print('{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(seconds // 3600 % 24,
                                     seconds // 60 % 60,
                                     seconds % 60))
    time.sleep(1.0)
    seconds += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```py
seconds = 57
minutes = 0
hours = 0

while seconds < 60:
    print(seconds,':',minutes,':',hours)
    seconds += 1
    # minutes += 1
    # hours += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes += 1
    if minutes == 60:
        # seconds = 0
        minutes = 0
        hours += 1
```

Comment: у вас как и у автора ошибка вот тут `elif minutes == 60:`

Comment: @Zhihar Да Вы правы поправил